# Error with spring-boot-maven-plugin when trying to lauch web app (Spring Vaadin)

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, spring-boot, vaadin

hello i'm a beginner in J2EE and web app and i've try to follow a simple get Started from spring (with vaadin for making my UI) https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/

When i lauch the command spring-boot:run i got the error below :

```
    [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ SampleJPA_Vaadin ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:492)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.456 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-21T20:41:09+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project SampleJPA_Vaadin: An exception occurred while running. org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner: org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

After few research on the net it seams that the CommandLineRunner Class isn't in the jar after the compile process.
But i'm not very comfortable with maven and the process of compiling web app.
So if you can explain me or just give me some link for explanation it would be great, thank you .

Here also my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.metaverse</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleJPA_Vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleJPA_Vaadin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.3.1</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following to your spring boot maven plugin config

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
   <execution>
   <goals><goal>repackage</goal></goals>
 <executions>
</plugin>
```

This will allow you to create a runnable fat jar with all the dependencies. You will get rid of the issue

Comment: i just realize that CommandLineRunner is an interface and the error is a ClassNotFOundExeption is there a link ?

Comment: Sorry but I insist that it is a build error. Either there is smth wrong with your maven installation or config, or in your project config.

Comment: yes i agree i assume the code is not bad because i follow a tutorial but i'm not familiarl with maven and J2EE environment. I will show you my maven config but what i need to do for my project config

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have the `spring-boot-starter` dependency anywhere, or it's being transitively ignored by your vaadin dependency.  You should explicitly include it ([referenced by this example online](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-non-web-application-example/)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for silly question, do you have a Class, with  public static void main in it :) ?

I just made a Project with your pom, and it needed a Class with main Method to run.

It would help, if you would post your Project on github :)